# Pulse when dimming lights by setting duty cycle of PCA9685

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pickle, led, servo

I have a AC current dimmer (MPDMv4.1) that takes a PWM signal to dim a halogen bulb. The PWM signal is coming from a PCA9685 servo HAT.

This works just perfectly with the following code:

```
from board import SCL, SDA
import busio
from adafruit_pca9685 import PCA9685

ic2_bus = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)
pca = PCA9685(i2c_bus)
pca.frequency = 1000

while True:
    value = input(„Enter a value from 0 to 100“)
    duty_cycle = int(round((100 - int(val))/100 * 57000)) 
    pca.channels[15].duty_cycle = duty_cycle
```

My problem occurs if I put the PCA9685 object initialization inside the endless loop, as such:

```
from board import SCL, SDA
import busio
from adafruit_pca9685 import PCA9685

ic2_bus = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)

while True:
    pca = PCA9685(i2c_bus)
    pca.frequency = 1000
    value = input(„Enter a value from 0 to 100“)
    duty_cycle = int(round((100 - int(val))/100 * 57000)) 
    pca.channels[15].duty_cycle = duty_cycle
```

It does of course not make sense to put the initialization inside the loop in this example. But my program is looping through different temperature sensors and based on the derived temperatures dims lights. The dimming is done in a separate process, because there is supposed to be a gradual change of the actual value to the target value to make the change smoother. I cannot wait for this to end with the main process, so I started a subprocess that takes care of this. But every time this process is started, the PCA9685 object has to be newly generated, and I get this pulse of bright light, which is not acceptable for my application. This pulse happens also when I‘m not actually changing the duty cycle, just by generating the object. It‘s only visible when the light is far from maximum power.

I tried to pickle the PCA9685 object and give it to the dimming process as an argument, but `_io.FileIO` objects cannot be pickled.

I also tried several different libraries, it’s always the same. Hence my question: Does anybody know how this is caused? Is this inevitable when establishing the connection? Can it potentially be circumvented?

Best and many thanks,
Gero

Comment: Can you share more of your code? I'm not quite understanding why you cannot instantiate `PCA9685` once and utilize it's methods. I suspect this is likely just a code structuring issue.

Comment: I have been thinking about the architecture before posting my question and came to the conclusion that it‘s not possible any other way.

Now after I‘ve read your comment I tried to reduce the code to an extend that it would be easily readable here. While doing that, I understood how I have to rearrange in order to instantiate only once.

So thanks for your comment!